# Is it a tautology?

Tags: logic

I have this:

$$(p \lor q) \oplus (\lnot p \land \lnot q)  $$

Here are the steps I took:

First I took the equivalence of  $$p \oplus q \equiv (p \land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land q)$$

Let $a= p \lor q$ and $b=(\lnot p \land \lnot q)$

Which gave me this:

$$ ((p \lor q)\land \lnot(\lnot p \land \lnot q)) \lor (\lnot(p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \land q) )$$

$$ \equiv (p\lor q) \lor (p \land \lnot q) \land (\lnot p \land q) $$
$$ \equiv (p\lor q) \lor ((p\land\lnot p)\land(\lnot q \land q))  $$
$$ \equiv (p\lor q) \lor (F\land F)  $$
$$ \equiv (p\lor q) \lor F  $$
$$ \equiv (p\lor q)  $$

I end up with a contigency... Anyone care to explain where I went wrong, or is the question wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $a\oplus b\equiv(a\land\neg b)\lor(\neg a\land b)$ with $a=p\lor q$ and $b=\neg p\land\neg q$, so the correct expansion is

$$\Big((p\lor q)\land\neg(\neg p\land\neg q)\Big)\lor\Big(\neg(p\lor q)\land(\neg p\land\neg q)\Big)\;;$$

in your version the second conjunct of the second disjunct is $\neg p\land q$, so it’s missing a negation. You also appear to have made a mistake in going from there to the next line: with your error in the first line you should get

$$(p\lor q)\lor\Big(\neg p\land\neg q)\land(\neg p\land q)\Big)$$

in the second line. After the initial error is corrected that becomes

$$(p\lor q)\lor\Big(\neg p\land\neg q)\land(\neg p\land\neg q)\Big)\;,$$

which simplifies to $(p\lor q)\lor(\neg p\land\neg q)\equiv(p\lor q)\lor\neg(p\lor q)$, which is clearly a tautology.

An easier approach, I think, is to note that $\neg p\land\neg q\equiv\neg(p\lor q)$, so that the original expression is equivalent to $(p\lor q)\oplus\neg(p\lor q)$, and show that $r\oplus\neg r$ is a tautology.

Comment: You're right... I see where I missed that negation. Thanks for noticing. Appreciate the help! And yes, that is an easier approach.

Comment: @Dimitri: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Recognizing that $\;\oplus\;$ is just the same as $\;\not\equiv\;$, it is easy to prove this:
\begin{align}
& p \lor q \;\not\equiv\; \lnot p \land \lnot q \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"using $(0)$ below"} \\
& p \lor q \;\equiv\; \lnot(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"use DeMorgan on right hand side"} \\
& p \lor q \;\equiv\; p \lor q \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"tautology"} \\
& \text{true} \\
\end{align}
So basically this uses the fact that $$(0) \;\;\; p \not\equiv q \:\:\equiv\:\: p \equiv \lnot q$$ or (if you prefer) $\;p \oplus q \;\equiv\; p \equiv \lnot q\;$.

But it depends on which laws you're allowed to use as a starting point...

Comment: I now see that I've basically duplicated the "easier approach" from the answer by @BrianMScott. Sorry for that.